# Is it possible to hide class names in jest output on failure?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

When my test fails to find an element on a page, Jest prints out the DOM to my screen. I'm using MUI and it makes a mess with classnames, like this:

```html
<div
class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root css-1akjbnu-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root"
>
<label
  class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-colorPrimary MuiFormLabel-filled MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined css-rrjzhf-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root"
  data-shrink="true"
  for="application-name-yq40gwnkmyh"
  id="application-name-yq40gwnkmyh-label"
>
  Application name
</label>
```

It's really hard to read it. I wonder if there's an option to hide class names from this output, and only leave the DOM elements?

Update: seems it's `react-testing-library`, not jest. But anyway, looks like there's no such option: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/#debugging

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's an option to hide the class names from the output when using `react-testing-library`. However, you can try using a DOM inspector tool like the Chrome DevTools to inspect the elements on the page and see the structure of the DOM. This can be useful for debugging and understanding the structure of the page, without having to sift through the class names.

You can also consider using a custom formatter for Jest, such as the pretty-quick package, which can format the test output in a more readable manner. This might make it easier to understand the output of the tests, even if the class names are still present.

If you still have trouble reading the output, you can consider using a separate tool for visualizing the DOM, such as a browser extension or a standalone application. These tools can provide a visual representation of the DOM that is easier to understand, which can be helpful when debugging your tests.